# Ajust table rows after after modifications (Delete, Insert Update) on Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

On table "Types", the rows order shall be controled by the field "ordem".

After any data modifications(Delete, Insert or Update), the others rows should be ajusted to assure correct exbitions of the content.

To implement this funcionality, I tried to code a trigger to correct the values in two similar ways (I, II).

```sql
CREATE TABLE TYPES (
    ID          NUMBER          PRIMARY KEY,
    ARG_1       VARCHAR2(20)        NOT NULL,
    ARG_2       VARCHAR2(20)        NOT NULL,
    ORDEM       NUMBER              NOT NULL
);

-----------------------------------------------  
-- I
----------------------------------------------- 

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TGR_TYPES
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON TYPES
  DECLARE
    V_NORDEM NUMBER := NEW.ORDEM;    
    CURSOR C_TYPES IS
       SELECT ID, ORDEM
         FROM TYPES  
        WHERE ORDEM >= V_NORDEM;
  BEGIN 
    IF UPDATING OR INSERTING THEN
        BEGIN     
            FOR R_TYPE IN C_TYPES LOOP
                UPDATE TYPEA SET ORDEM = (ORDEM + 1) WHERE ID = R_TYPE.ID;
             END LOOP;
        END;
    ELSE
        DECLARE V_ORDEM NUMBER := 0;
        BEGIN
            FOR R_TYPE IN C_TYPES LOOP
                UPDATE OSP_TP_ADDR_COMPLEMENTOS SET ORDEM = (V_ORDEM + 1) WHERE ID = R_COMPLEMENTO.ID;
            END LOOP;
        END;
    END IF;
  END;

  /*
  ERROR ON COMPILE:

    ORA-04082: referências NEW ou OLD não permitidas nos gatilhos de nível de tabela
    04082. 00000 -  "NEW or OLD references not allowed in table level triggers"
    *Cause:    The trigger is accessing "new" or "old" values in a table trigger.
    *Action:   Remove any new or old references.

  */

-----------------------------------------------  
-- II 
----------------------------------------------- 
CREATE OR REPLACE
  TRIGGER TRG_TYPES
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON TYPES
  FOR EACH ROW

  BEGIN 
    IF UPDATING OR INSERTING THEN
        BEGIN     
            FOR TP IN (
                SELECT *
                FROM TYPES  
                WHERE ORDEM >= :NEW.ORDEM
            ) LOOP
                UPDATE TYPES SET ORDEM = (ORDEM + 1) WHERE ID = TP.ID;
                COMMIT;
             END LOOP;
        END;
    ELSE
        DECLARE V_ORDEM NUMBER := 0;
        BEGIN
            FOR TP IN (
                SELECT *
                FROM TYPES
                ORDER BY ORDEM
            ) LOOP
                UPDATE TYPES SET ORDEM = (V_ORDEM + 1) WHERE ID = TP.ID;
             END LOOP;
        END;
    END IF;
  END;

  /*
  ERROR ON UPDATE:

    UPDATE TYPES 
    SET ORDEM = 14
    WHERE ID=26
    Relatório de erros -
    ORA-04091: a tabela TYPES é mutante; talvez o gatilho/função não possa localizá-la
    ORA-06512: em "", line 9
    ORA-04088: erro durante a execução do gatilho ''
  */
```

I expect one solution to assure the trigger operation or other approach to the integrity of the order field. I have thinking about tring the Index-Organized Table structure, but not sure.

Comment: IOT would not help there, IOT is only about storage, not data contents. One question about your motive in writing a trigger : do you expect the user of your application to bet able to control the display order of the rows?

Comment: "After any data modifications adjust the other rows" - that is certainly not a good idea. Can you elaborate your question? What exactly are you trying to do? What logic is behind the ordering? Is it just consecutive numbers?

Comment: This is a really bad idea. Display order is a UI capability, so it is something which should be handled in the client or the data access layer, say by sorting on a key column or something equally meaningful. But to really understand why this is a bad idea, consider this scenario: you insert a new record while at the same time I delete an existing record - what should the order be now?